# Android downloading series of files Not working

Tags: java, android, android-layout, download, android-asynctask

I need function that download files by passing name and urls, so that i can download series of files in android app.

So went ahead and created something like this:

```
public void doDownload (String fileName, String url){
    File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();               
    File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath() + "/Content/"); 
    if(dir.exists()==false) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }

    try{
        URL url = new URL(url);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        // this will be useful so that you can show a typical 0-100% progress bar
        int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();
        Log.i("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + fileLength);

        // download the file
        InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(dir + fileName);   
        byte data[] = new byte[1024];
        long total = 0;
        int count;
        while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;

            output.write(data, 0, count);
        }

        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
    }
}
```

XML: Added permission

Now when i call this function:

```
doDownload(String img.png, String http://server.com);
```

It returns no files. 
What is wrong here?

Comment: currently u are calling  `doDownload` method inside loop to download more then one file?

Comment: No im calling this method in, after user pick the option, e.g: once user pick option 1, than option 1 files url and name will execute with doDownload(url, filename) to download and store file in sdcard.

Comment: Have a look at similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog

Comment: Yes, and i did try to do function like  `protected String doInBackground(String... sUrl, String fileName)` and try to pass file name but didnt work.

Comment: What error messages are you getting? When you step through your code, where is it breaking?

Comment: ERROR: `android.os.NetwirkOnMainThreadException`

Comment: Sounds like you're not threading your download. Is this true?

Comment: @TheCapn: Sorry but im new to android, so should i be doing it?

Comment: @Dixit - Yes, your `NetworkOnMainThreadException` indicates you're trying to download something from the main thread which isn't allowed. They do this to prevent lengthy pauses which appear to the user as if the program froze.

Comment: Thanks you all, I have fixed it! Also you can add me on google + https://plus.google.com/103405375045630693169/

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using the download manager to download the files. you can try using DownloadManager. see the android developer site. check this link: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html